# Python: Error decoding JSON

Tags: python, json

I want my script to get EXT_IP from JSON at http://usa-archer.com/ip.php.

I have checked my JSON code and it validated as correct at http://jsonlint.com/
But for some reason python gives an error that it cant be decoded.

I use this later on in my script to say "Your current IP is" + EXT_IP["ip"]

Python CODE:

```
EXT_IP = json.loads(urllib.urlopen("http://example.com/ip.php").read())
```

Python ERROR:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: Try reading the JSON into a temporary location and printing it between calls. It may not be sending precisely what you wrote.

Comment: Hint: try printing the output of `urllib.urlopen("http://usa-archer.com/ip.php").read()` in your console.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, after printing it I realized it was being blocked by CloudFlare. So CloudFlare recognized it as a malicious script

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

print urllib.urlopen("http://example.com/ip.php").read()

which showed that the request from the python script was being blocked by CloudFlare

Thanks Danniel Roseman